# R Shiny - adding a for loop to downloadHandler

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I am trying to add a `for` loop to the `downloadHandler` function in order to download `n` files, where `n` is a user input. In the example below, for simplicity's sake, I am not using `n`, I'm just trying to get the loop to work, then I will modify the code and add reactivity, etc.

Here is the standard code for a single download:

```
output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
   filename = function() {paste('test', '.csv', sep='') },
   content = function(file) {write.csv(df, file)}
)
```

I tried to add a `for` loop to this with no success, here:

```
output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
   for (i in 1:5) {
      filename = function() {paste('test', i, '.csv', sep='') }
      content = function(file) {write.csv(df, file)}
   }
)
```

and here:

```
 output$downloadData <- for (i in 1:5) {
      downloadHandler(
             filename = function() {paste('test', i, '.csv', sep='')},
             content = function(file) {write.csv(df, file)}
      )
 }
```

This is a simplified app that can download 1 file, `test.csv`. I'd like to get this to download multiple files with one click of the button. So, let's say 3 files, `test1.csv`, `test2.csv`, `test3.csv` :

```
library(shiny)

#### SERVER ####
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  df = as.data.frame(1:10)
  output$table = renderDataTable({df})

  #create download output
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {paste('test', '.csv', sep='')},
    content = function(file) {write.csv(df, file)}
  )
})

#### UI ####
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      h3(textOutput("input")),
      numericInput("n", h5("n"), value = ''),
      downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download')  
    ),
    mainPanel(
      dataTableOutput("table")
    )
  )
))

shinyApp(ui<-ui, server<-server) #launch app
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: have a look here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/shiny-discuss/qGN3jeCbFRY/xOW5qoVrr94J

Comment: Thanks, but the solution in this link creates as many buttons as files. I'm looking for a way to download all files with one click, if possible. Or if they can somehow be compressed to a single file somewhere along the line...

Comment: I think the examples there are more than enough to loop through it, creating files with different names